# How to concatenate a varibale from a function in a form action with Django?

Tags: python, django

i want to concatenate a variable in a form action. for example:

```
<form action="{% url 'addAlumn' ${id} %}" method="POST">
```

im sure im wrong but i dont have idea how to do this.

this is my function:

```
<script>
function alumno(obj, obj2, obj3, obj4) {
    id = obj;
    var no_certificado = obj2;
    var nom = obj3;
    var curp = obj4;
    $("#nombre").val(nom);
    $("#cert").val(no_certificado);
    $("#curp").val(curp);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Template tags are computed on the server side. Your server has no idea of what is going on in your Javascript code on the client side. You may consider submitting using Javascript instead of using a form action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the form url, remove the ID from urls.py and get the object with the post request. Something like this:

Form

```
<form action="{% url 'editarAlumno'  %}" method="POST">
```

urls.py

```
path('NuevaSolicitud/editarAlumno/', login_required(views.EditarAlumno), name='editarAlumno'),
```

views.py

```
def EditarAlumno(request):
id = request.POST["id"]
alumno = Alumnos.objects.get(pk=id)
...
...
...
# Make sure you save your object before redirecting
alumno.save()

return redirect('Alumnos')
```

Comment: that sounds great. i'll try to do and comment if it work! :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see your form action should be '=' to not ':' I'm not sure what the function is used for, looks like you are adding values to the form.

You also need to remove $ from 'id'

Abit more info on what you are trying to do can make it easier to give more help

```
<form action="{% url 'addAlumn' id %}" method="POST">
```

Comment: this is my urls.py: `path('NuevaSolicitud/editarAlumno/<int:pk>', login_required(views.EditarAlumno), name='editarAlumno'),` and this my views.py: `def EditarAlumno(request, idAlumno):
    alumno = Alumnos.objects.get(pk=idAlumno)
    alumno.nombre_alumno = request.POST["nom"]
    alumno.no_certificado = request.POST["cert"]
    alumno.CURP = request.POST["curp"]
    return redirect('Alumnos')`. i show the students in a table and i can add, delete and update a student from the table. so to update a student i haveto send the id in the action but i using modal forms and i cant get the id

Comment: the $ in id is because i tried to use javascript or jquery to concatenate a variable where i catch the student's id

Answer (score 0):

this is my table:

```
<tbody>
                {% if lista_alumnos %}
                    {% for alumno in lista_alumnos %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ alumno.no_certificado }}</td>
                        <td>{{ alumno.nombre_alumno }}</td>
                        <td>{{ alumno.CURP }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#editEmployeeModal" onclick="alumno('{{alumno.id}}','{{alumno.no_certificado}}','{{alumno.nombre_alumno}}','{{alumno.CURP}}')" class="edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target=""><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a href="" class="delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteEmployeeModal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
```